# Best way to let all the instance in a autoscale group if I updated a file in one instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created an autoscaling group in EC2. For example, now the autoscaling group is expanded to 4 instances, and I have a web application running on Apache. Now, I updated one file (e.g index.php) and I need all 4 instances to have the new file index.php updated.

So how can I let all the 4 instances have the new index.php?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, imo, is to update your base AMI that you are using, and then slowly terminate your old instances so that the autoscale  group spins up new instances using the latest codebase you have installed on your base AMI.

Here is my answer to a similar question that may help:

[How to deploy and update app on multiply ec2 instances in Amazon Auto-scaling group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023388/how-to-deploy-and-update-app-on-multiply-ec2-instances-in-amazon-auto-scaling-gr)